# How to check dictionary if string value exist for conditional comparison

Tags: c#, if-statement, dictionary

if I want use dictionary with given values for conditional comparison in if-statement to pass implementation but avoid if-statement for listing of this values and get it from dictionary. So how to check dictionary, which contains 400 strings, if string value exist:

```
    Dictionary<int, string> set1 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                              {{ 1, "string1" }, { 2, "string2" } ... }; // 400 values
```

So seems like this way is wrong:

```
    string str = "string1";

    if (set1.ContainsKey(str) == true)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Contains");
    }
    else
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Does Not Contains");
    }
```

To get result for further condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContainsValue(value);

```
string str = "string1";

if (set1.ContainsValue(str) == true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Contains");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Does Not Contains");
}
```

or with linq:

```
using System.Linq;
...
string str = "string1";

if (set1.Values.Any(x => x == str))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Contains");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Does Not Contains");
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm a little confused, I do exactly the same you show in your answer in my example, am I right? except second one, but I've tried this way too. Sometimes it does not founds exist

Comment: @DefColin The first part of my answer is using `ContainsValue` instead of `ContainsKey`

Comment: @DefColin Thats correct. If you do know the specific key, then you can search for the key and retrieve it's value. But then you need to know the key ofc. But i suppose that's another question.

Comment: sorry, now I see, so I must get it thorough value and not the key for value. but I'm still not sure if it is better then if-statement for such case, because with if-statement  if chosen value exist, avoiding  and getting of non exist for example provided by if-statement itself, right? in this case If value exist and I need to find non exist at the same time, I must pass it again

Comment: @DefColin I'm a bit confused of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ValuesCollection of the dictionary to simplify your code:

```
    Dictionary<int, string> set1 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                          {{ 1, "string1" }, { 2, "string2" }};

    var valuesCollection = set1.Values;
    var str = "string1";
    Console.WriteLine(valuesCollection.FirstOrDefault(v => v == str) != null ? "Contains" : " Not contains");
```

Comment: hello, also answer.